# С++ Подключение заголовочных. Правильно ли так?

Tags: c++

Можно ли так делать. Создал STD_INCLUDES.h, который кругом подключаю заместо кучи инклюдов, в нем содержимое такого типа:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <locale>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Ещё есть #include <bits/stdc++.h>, в тему precompiled headers даже писать ничего не нужно в отдельном заголовке

Answer (score 6):

Это работает, это удобно. **Но только в маленьких проектах**. У вас нарастает функционал, вы включаете в этот хедер все больше и больше других, и может настать момент, когда сборка проекта будет занимать куууууучу времени.

Это происходит по той причине, что каждый заголовок вставляется в файл, в котором вы его `include`-те, и компилятору приходится обрабатывать тонны кода, который тут и вовсе ни к чему.

К тому же, если вы решите, что вам что-то из инклюдов уже не нужно, уберете это из файла со всеми заголовками, у вас может что-то сломаться. И если проект большой, то это такая головная боль...

**Поэтому совет - включайте лишь необходимые заголовки.**

В виде исключения - можете собрать в один заголовок те заголовочные файлы, которые **часто используются вместе**. Например в физическом движке `Box2D` есть заголовок `Box2D.h`, который имеет вид:

```
#include "Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h"
#include "Box2D/Common/b2Draw.h"
.....
#include "Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2WeldJoint.h"
#include "Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2WheelJoint.h"
```

Потому что вы, скорее всего, не будете использовать какой-то один компонент отдельно от всего движка, и вам проще подключить один заголовок.

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138259/is-it-a-good-idea-to-put-all-of-your-includes-in-one-header-file) дубликат с англоязычного стака.

Кстати, существует еще такая практика, как **предварительно откомпилированные заголовки (precompiled headers)**. Подробнее о них можно почитать, к примеру, [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#GCC).

Comment: Спасибо, примерно также и представлял себе

Comment: Я бы даже сказал что предкомпилированные заголовки просто НЕОБХОДИМО использовать. По личным наблюдениям, на среднем проекте с ~50 файлов может сократить время сборки в 2 раза. Ну и конечно простота использования, когда подключаешь только один файл и доступны все библиотеки.

Comment: @Александр я писал чисто по теории, ибо опыта работы с сколько-нибудь объемными проектами на c++ у меня не много) но спасибо за информацию, это довольно забавно.

Comment: А зачем в МАЛОМ проекте все эти инклуды? как раз скорее в большом нужны...

Comment: @Mikhailo если у вас три файла, и вы не хотите писать инклюды в каждом))0) На самом деле да, в малом проекте они, конечно же, ни к чему. Harry в своем ответе описал оптимизации, которые может произвести компилятор для ускорения сборки. Если вас устраивает время сборки - то используйте в большом проекте на здоровье)

Answer (score 3):

Это имеет смысл, если вы используете предкомпилированные заголовки, а вот такой заголовок *идет первым*, без каких бы то ни было `#define`'ов или `#include`'ов перед ним - тогда все это будет предкомпилировано, что может даже ускорить работу.

Просто так тягать за собой всю библиотеку, если нужен, скажем, только вывод в `cout` - смысла нет. Даже с предкомпиляцией...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Сошлюсь на авторитетов :) - "Шаблоны С++" Вандевурда-Джосаттиса- Грегора от 2017 года. Цитирую:

---

> Некоторые программисты считают, что лучше включить в файл некоторые
>   дополнительные ненужные заголовочные файлы, но обеспечить возможность
>   ускорить трансляцию за счет использования предкомпилированного
>   заголовочного файла. Такое решение может существенно облегчить
>   управление стратегией включения. Например, обычно относительно просто
>   создать заголовочный файл с именем `std.hpp`, который включает в себя
>   все стандартные заголовки:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> #include <vector>
> #include <deque>
> #include <list>
> ...
> ```
>
> Затем этот файл может быть предкомпилирован, и каждый файл программы,
>   использующий стандартную библиотеку, просто начинается следующим
>   образом:
>
> ```
> #include "std.hpp"
> ...
> ```
>
> Обычно это требует некоторого времени для предкомпиляции, но в системе
>   с достаточным объемом памяти схема с предкомпилированным заголовочным
>   файлом позволяет работать значительно быстрее, чем требуется почти
>   любому стандартному заголовочному файлу без предварительной
>   компиляции. Стандартные заголовочные файлы особенно удобно
>   использовать таким образом, потому что они редко изменяются, а
>   следовательно, предкомпилированный заголовочный файл для файла
>   `std.hpp` может быть построен один раз. В противном случае
>   предкомпилированные заголовочные файлы обычно являются частью
>   конфигурации зависимостей проекта (например, обновляются по мере
>   необходимости популярной программой make или соответствующим
>   инструментарием интегрированной среды разработки (IDE)).
>
> Одним из привлекательных подходов к управлению предкомпилированными
>   заголовочными файлами является создание слоев предкомпилированных
>   заголовочных файлов, которые образуются из наиболее широко
>   используемых и стабильных заголовочных файлов (как, например, наш
>   заголовочный файл `std.hpp`), для которых не ожидается внесение
>   изменений, а потому имеет смысл их предварительная компиляция. Однако,
>   если заголовочные файлы находятся в постоянном развитии, их
>   предкомпиляция может потребовать больше времени, чем даст экономия при
>   повторном их использовании. Ключевой концепцией этого подхода является
>   то, что предкомпилированные заголовочные файлы более стабильного слоя
>   могут быть повторно использованы для улучшения времени компиляции
>   менее стабильных заголовочных файлов. Предположим, например, что в
>   дополнение к нашему заголовочному файлу `std.hpp` (который мы
>   предварительно скомпилировали), мы также определили заголовочный файл
>   `core.hpp`, который включает дополнительные возможности, специфичные
>   для нашего проекта, но тем не менее достигшие определенного уровня
>   стабильности:
>
> ```
> #include "std.hpp"
> #include "core_data.hpp"
> #include "core_algos.hpp"
> ...
> ```
>
> Поскольку этот файл начинается с `#include "std.hpp"`, компилятор
>   может загрузить соответствующий предкомпилированный заголовок и
>   продолжить работу со следующими строками без перекомпиляции всех
>   стандартных заголовков. Когда файл будет полностью обработан, может
>   быть создан новый предкомпилированный заголовочный файл. Затем
>   приложения могут использовать `#include "core.hpp"` для обеспечения
>   быстрого доступа к большому количеству функциональности, потому что
>   компилятор может загрузить последний предкомпилированный заголовочный
>   файл.

---

Простите за обильное цитирование :)

Comment: Обрамите процитированное в теги цитирования плиз.

Comment: Для цитирования достаточно одного `>` перед каждым абзацем.

Comment: @alexolut Мне проще было выделить весь текст и нажать единственную кнопочку, чем бегать по абзацам...

Comment: А, ну да, я просто как-то вручную привык `>` вставлять :)

Comment: спасибо за большое объяснение